# How to calculate time difference between two rising edges at an external interrupt pin STM32?

Tags: stm32, gpio-external-interrupt

I am using STM32 Nucelo board mostly with HAL and I set one GPIO pin as an external interrupt pin. And I want to measure the time between two consecutive rising edges fed to this pin. So far, I have the following callback in main.c where I need the section to calculate the time difference between two rising edges.

```
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{

    if (GPIO_Pin == myInterrupt_Input_Pin)
    {


    }
}
```

How could that be implemented so that we can have the time difference diff between two rising edges in μs?(with or without HAL does not matter)

Comment: Timers can be used to keep track of time. But why do you want to do it using EXTI interrupts? Timers already have hardware input capture features to give capture interrupts with latched timestamp on rising signal edges so you can achieve much better than 1us resolution.

Comment: Because EXTI manually triggers some other things as well. It wont be periodic.

Comment: You'll still get an interrupt from the timer capture event like EXTI would.

Comment: Start timer on one interrupt. Read the timer on the other interrupt (and stop it). Or have a forever timer running and just read the timer value both times then compare.

Comment: I see but thats the logic part. I ask this question which HAL function or registers to be used. I need help on the implementation part.

Comment: If you don't know how to use the HAL, have you read the HAL manual? Another route is to generate code to initialize timers in CubeIDE/CubeMX and just read the counter register directly in the interrupt.

Comment: The problem is the HAL manual does not explain what HAL functions do. One has to guess from their names.

Comment: I would strongly reject the statement that the HAL functions are not described. If you got to e.g. the F4 HAL manual (first thing that came up) https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00105879-description-of-stm32f4-hal-and-ll-drivers-stmicroelectronics.pdf Also there is usually a quite detailled description in the source files itself.

Comment: Also the HAL manual wont tell you what registers to use, just how to access them. Which registers to use and what to do with them is in the datasheet of you microcontroller. Translating this to HAL function calls is usually the easiest part (especially since HAL functions are named quite descriptive).

Comment: @max See HAL_TIM_PWM_PulseFinishedCallback has the description "PWM Pulse finished callback in non-blocking mode." It is really not even technical description. What is meant by this is not clear. They could write couple of sentence to make these functions clear even with some examples.

Comment: @user1999 I think it is pretty clear. And yes, it is a perfectly fine technical description. If I'd REALLY needed to know what was going on, I can still look in the source code.